# Adding a field to a matlab struct

Tags: matlab

I'm having the following problem which I can't believe there to be a simple solution for. At any rate a google search wasn't succesful.

Suppose I make the following struct

```
teststruct = struct('field1',{'a','b','c'});
```

Now I want to add another field called 'field2' filled with 'd', 'e' and 'f'. Basically I want to achieve the result I would have achieved by directly doing.

```
teststruct2 = struct('field1',{'a','b','c'}, 'field2', {'d','e','f'});
```

I tried several solutions and the closest I got was

```
[teststruct(:).field2] = {'d';'e';'f'};
```

This however puts the entire cell on the right hand side in it's entirety in the objects 'field2' field.

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Just lift out the instantiation

```
teststruct.field1 = {'a','b','c'}
teststruct.field2 = {'d','e','f'}
```